# JQuery - Push method JSONArray

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm doing the push method between two Arrays to create a bigger Array. The two simple arrays I want to fix are:

```
[{"id":"11"},{"color":"blue","value":"14"}] 
[{"id":"11"},{"color":"green","value":"25"}]
```

The code to push the two arrays is:

```
var totjunt = $('body').data('cesta_list').push(array_of_bought_colors_new);
```

With `$('body').data('cesta_list');` I save the first array and then i try to push the second array.

Using `console.log(JSON.stringify(totjunt));` I print the value  throught the console but the problem is that the console prints only a number 2.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp push returns the new array length, not the new array

Answer (score 4):

You're logging the result of the `push()` call, not the resulting array.  Try this:

```
$('body').data('cesta_list').push(array_of_bought_colors_new);
var totjunt = $('body').data('cesta_list');
```

More specifically, `push()` [returns the length of the new array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push#Returns), not the array itself.

Answer (score 3):

[`.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) doesn't return a new array.  It returns the array's new length.  The array is updated in-place.

Comment: @jmar777: Knock yourself out, enjoy the link :)